# overlay points over polygon in R with a large data frame

Tags: r, r-sp, geos

I am using

```
pc100m <- gBuffer(pc, width=100, byid=TRUE )
```

and

```
test2 <- over(pc100m, Dataset_tr, returnList = TRUE)
```

With a small data frame (<5,000 obs; the same data frame is used to create a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and SpatialPointsDataFrame), it works really well. But when I have a large data frame, only the first line (pc100m) manages to work. I assume it's because the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and SpatialPointsDataFrame are too large (~250,000 obs. each). My alternative was to split my data frame into sections and then run a loop. I was just wondering if there was another alternative that could be faster.

Comment: unless you move the operation to something like PostGIS, doing it in chunks (perhaps even in parallel) is probably the way to go.

Comment: what is the class of `Dataset_tr`?

Comment: Edzer, Dataset_tr is a SpatialPointsDataFrame and pc100m is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Comment: If all you want to do is find points in `pc` that are less than 100 distance units away from points in `Dataset_tr`, you might also want to try `sp::zerodist` with argument `zero` set to 100. It doesn't return a list, but a two column matrix with index pairs.